# How do I disconnect from Byobu in a console?

Tags: console, byobu, disconnect

I'm using byobu on the server. Then I logged in my kde I just close a tab with byobu session. But how I can disconnect if I'll use just console terminal? I mean one of Ctrl+ things.

Answer (score 31):

You can either use:

- <kbd>F6</kbd>

or

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> then press <kbd>d</kbd> to detach

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Interesting. Wish we had some way of marking an answer as canonical.

Comment: Probably better idea have this as useful message in some edge of screen.

Comment: The information is in the `F1` - `Help -- Quick Start Guide`, but you need to scroll down to see